# Why are one wire temperature sensor readings so slow?

Tags: sensor, temperature

I've just connected several waterproof DS18B20 sensors to my Raspberry Pi B+ V1.2 running Jessie Lite.

Working on the command line, why does it take so long to display the contents of the sensor's `w1_slave` file? I.e. if I

```
cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-nnnnnnnnnnnnn/w1_slave
```

why does it seem to take a full second to get my reading?

I understand this is perfectly normal. My guess is there's a relatively slow (maybe 200 bits/sec) serial conversation going on in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [datasheet currently hosted by Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/DS18B20.pdf):

> Converts Temperature to 12-Bit Digital Word in 750ms (Max)

From [s445203's answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14285/32756):

> ...as far as I can tell from the w1_therm source code here *[link now
>   dead]*... the w1_therm driver has the 750ms wait value hard coded in
>   it.

I'm also seeing reports of slow refresh rates on both the [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77611) and [Adafruit forums](http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=54352). It looks like it's just a slow sensor with a 750ms refresh rate dictated by the driver. It's completely epoxy encased, so it will take some amount of time for any temperature change to propagate through the casing; even if it updated faster it wouldn't necessarily have useful new values.

Comment: Yeah. I thought as much. It's not so much about the refresh rate for me; rather about figuring out how to architect the program so that when the web page queries the three devices, it doesn't take 3 seconds to refresh the page. I'll get there. Thanks.

Comment: @KDM why not just continously read the devices in a background process into 3 files in /tmp then have your web page read the latest from there.

Comment: Indeed, it's "about figuring out how to architect the program so that when the web page queries the three devices..." Thanks.